# Using Salesforce Partner API from community portal

Tags: soap-api, community, java

I've created a custom button on the opportunity layout which calls out to an external java app. It passes the session id and the partner API URL. The external app then creates a SOAP binding (leveraging the partner wsdl downloaded from Setup). The first thing I do with the binding is call SoapBindingStub.getUserInfo().

My org has the Communities feature enabled to allow partner users to log in through community portals. When I click the custom button coming from a community portal, the above fails and I see "Caused by: (411)Length Required" in the stack. It works just fine if I click the button coming from salesforce (rather than a community portal).

Any ideas what's causing the RemoteException? I'm using the same user for both scenarios. Here's the full stack trace:

```
Caused by: (411)Length Required at 
org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPSender.java:218) at 
org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32) at 
org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118) at 
org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83) at 
org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165) at 
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784) at 
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767) at 
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443) at 
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366) at 
org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812) at 
com.sforce.soap.partner.SoapBindingStub.getUserInfo(SoapBindingStub.java:3994)
```

I'm wondering if the URL is the cause. Is there some setting/permission in communities that needs to be set in order to do this? Here are the URLS observed:

https://myCommunityDomainName.force.com/myCommunityName/services/Soap/u/28.0/00Di0000000eG2r -does not work

https://na15.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/28.0/00Di0000000eG2r -works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found an answer for this.

I used SOAP UI to try making these calls, and I got a more helpful error message: "API access is disabled for Communities". From there I was able to find a blog post with some details.

Apparently, when coming from a Community portal, the API.Parner_Server_URL should not be used to make API calls back to Salesforce (what?!). Salesforce support says to use the endpoint that would result from a standard salesforce user clicking the link (na15.salesforce.com/... as seen above, for example). They claim it is working as designed, which makes me wonder what the heck API.Parner_Server_URL is any good for when coming though a community portal.

Here's the blog post for reference: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/APIs-and-Integration/API-Access-Disabled-for-Communities/td-p/644035

EDIT: See Dana's answer below; according to the author, support for this has been added as of Summer '15.

Comment: For some reason, security to Communities portals isn't handled the same as normal SF. SSO and other certain other protocols seem to be a version behind from what I've been reading in the docs. Its a though they released Communities just a bit before it was fully ready for prime time. I suspect we'll be seeing a lot of "new features" with each new SF release that arrives. ;)

Comment: That could be. Maybe using the URL provided through the community portal will work as expected in one of the coming releases. I hope. It seems silly to require a work-around from something like this.

Comment: Did you ever have any success in actually getting this working?  Did anything improve in the subsequent SF releases?

Comment: I haven't tried since, but the Winter '14 release notes make it sound as if it is supported now. See the section titled "Improved Communities API Support" here: https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_winter14_release_notes.pdf

Comment: @CDelaney, I am facing the same issue now. How did you manage to retrieve the Standard Salesforce user Api URL?

Comment: @SuryatejMukkamalla We ended up adding a configurable domain variable in our app, and stripped the communities domain off of the one provided by SF. However, the answer below suggests that it should be working as of Summer 15

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I tried the workaround posted below and was able to get the correct partner URL.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that as of Summer 15, the RESTful Identity URL returns a usable `partner` url:

```
https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/{version}/orgidorgidorgidorgid
```

Additionally, the `API Enabled` option must be selected on the community user's profile.  From there I was able to access the API on behalf of a community user.

```
{
   "id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/orgidorgidorgidorgid/useriduseriduserid",
   "asserted_user":true,
   "user_id":"useriduseriduserid",
   "organization_id":"orgidorgidorgidorgid",
   "username":"custom@custom.com",
   "nick_name":"custom",
   "display_name":"custom",
   "email":"custom@custom.com",
   "email_verified":true,
   "first_name":"custom",
   "last_name":"custom",
   "timezone":"America/Los_Angeles",
   "photos":{
      "picture":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/img/userprofile/default_profile_200.png",
      "thumbnail":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/img/userprofile/default_profile_45.png"
   },
   "addr_street":"123 Some Street",
   "addr_city":"Anytown",
   "addr_state":"PA",
   "addr_country":"USA",
   "addr_zip":"80000",
   "mobile_phone":null,
   "mobile_phone_verified":false,
   "status":{
      "created_date":null,
      "body":null
   },
   "urls":{
      "enterprise":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/{version}/orgidorgidorgidorgid",
      "metadata":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/{version}/orgidorgidorgidorgid",
      "partner":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/{version}/orgidorgidorgidorgid",
      "rest":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/",
      "sobjects":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/sobjects/",
      "search":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/search/",
      "query":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/query/",
      "recent":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/recent/",
      "profile":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/useriduseriduserid",
      "feeds":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/chatter/feeds",
      "groups":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/chatter/groups",
      "users":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/chatter/users",
      "feed_items":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v{version}/chatter/feed-items",
      "custom_domain":"https://custom-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com"
   },
   "active":true,
   "user_type":"POWER_PARTNER",
   "language":"en_US",
   "locale":"en_US",
   "utcOffset":-28800000,
   "last_modified_date":"2015-07-22T10:34:51-06:00",
   "is_app_installed":true
}
```