# JavaScript return Invalid Session ID?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Here, here is my JavaScript code within a VisualForce page. The query is guaranteed to return only one result. but I am getting "Invalid Session ID" exception. please help.

```
    function queryPricingModel()
    {
        sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';

        try
        {
            var myQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT BP__c FROM PC_BP_Matrix__c WHERE StartVolume__c <= annualVolume AND EndVolume__c > annualVolume");
            pcBP = myQuery;
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            alert(error.faultstring);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Last time I used AJAX toolkit, it was necessary to put the Session ID in a crazy magic global variable before loading the library:

```
<!-- this guy first -->
<script type="text/javascript">__sfdcSessionId = '{!$Api.Session_Id}';</script>

<!-- this guy second -->
<script src="/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain? I have my javascript in a separate file in the static resource. I know I can access the global variable from the js file. But I'm not sure how do I use the variable.

Comment: Worked great! / you're awesome - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the session Id:

```
 var sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
```

It looks like you are trying to set the SessionId, and not all Session Ids are the same:  [Different Session Ids in Different contexts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23277/different-session-ids-in-different-contexts)

Also, Salesforce provides [a good example for the AJAX Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Can you `alert()` that session id? Is it blank by any chance? Is the user authenticated (it's not something like a Site where any external user can get)?

You've used [salesforce-communities](/questions/tagged/salesforce-communities) - but for example [Using Salesforce Partner API from community portal](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16316/using-salesforce-partner-api-from-community-portal) indicates there are problems with API access in communities.

Can you try to rework your Visualforce page to either use pure Apex & VF or maybe some JS remoting?